# What is the difference between %.02f and %.2f?

Tags: objective-c, formatting, format-specifiers

What is the difference between %.02f and %.2f? 
From what I understand, whatever number comes after the point, indicates the number of decimal places to be displayed when converting a number to a string. But what does it mean when there are two numbers coming after the point as in %.02?

Comment: did you try printing using both format and see different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number after the `.` is the number of fractional digits to show. `02` and `2` are the same number - `2`. The `0` has no special meaning here.

There is no significance to a two digit number over a one digit number after the `.`. It's just a count. If you had `%.10f` you would get 10 fractional digits.

None of this is specific to Objective-C. It holds for any language that follows the [IEEE printf specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fprintf.html).

Comment: Awesome, thank you. What about if you have a number before the "."? Like as in %5.2f?

Comment: Go to the link I posted and read the spec. The `5` is the total width of the number including the `.` and the 2 fraction digits.

Answer (score 2):

say your value is 101

```
%f = 101.000000
%.f = 101
%.02f = 101.00
```